# Callback сервис, который звонит на один мобильный, потом на другой и объединяет их в один разговор?

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, callback

В общем есть задача, сделать callback сервис который по определенному событию, звонит на один мобильный, потом на другой мобильный, и объединяет их в один разговор. Логируется длительность разговора. Почти аналогичная система используется в приложении [«Будист»](http://budist.ru/landing/video/).

Я в этом абсолютно не разбираюсь, подскажите как это можно реализовать, или хотя бы в какую сторону гуглить и к каким специалистам обращаться. Во сколько примерно обойдется железо?

Страна — Украина, если это имеет значение.

Comment: Это относится к цифровой телефонии. 

В принципе, аппаратура (например Cisco) может обеспечивать gate для IP пакетов и API управления станцией, но это уже вопросы к провайдерам телефонии.

Можете также попробовать "покопать" протоколы GSM.

Comment: я думаю тот-же Будист использует sip гейты, в смысле провайдеров, железо в таком случае вамвообще не обойдется (не считая сервера) aterisk вполне справится с этой задачей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Железо - бесплатно. Вам понадобится аккаунт у какого-нибудь SIP-провайдера и Asterisk или FreeSwitch. Страна значения не имеет.